# Connection Refused to Server when using SOCKS5 Proxy and Tor C#

Tags: c#, sockets, proxy, client-server, tor

I have this code that uses SOCKS5 Proxy to connect to Tor and then tries to connect the Client to the remote Server on a VPS machine that runs a C# server. The problem is I can't establish the connection.

The Server is written in C#, it listens to connections on port 1604 and it's a hidden service meaning any traffic that comes trough port 1604 will be redirected to 127.0.0.1:1604 where my server listens.

## Test 1

When I connected directly to test if my client get make a HTTP request to a webserver on **port 80** it works, when i use the **.onion** address to access the webserver it works too. When I check **yougetsignal** using the **remote machine IP** it's open as you can see

[image]

Also here is the **torrc FILE** config

[image]

**GREAT EVERYTHING WORKS SO FAR, BUT WAIT A SECOND**

## Test 2

When I try to connect the client to my **standalone server (not a webserver)** directly it works like I expected it to do, but **when i try to use the HOSTNAME generated by tor.exe** (the same **HOSTNAME** I used in **Test 1**) i get **Connection Refused** and **General SOCKS server failure**.

[image]

I can't find what I'm doing wrong and why I can't reach my server, please assist me and thank you for your time.

## The Code

---

## Client

### Socks Code

```
public class ConnectionException : ApplicationException
{
    public ConnectionException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {

    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Provides sock5 functionality to clients (Connect only).
/// </summary>
public class SocksProxy
{

    private SocksProxy() { }

    #region ErrorMessages
    private static string[] errorMsgs = {
                                      "Operation completed successfully.",
                                      "General SOCKS server failure.",
                                      "Connection not allowed by ruleset.",
                                      "Network unreachable.",
                                      "Host unreachable.",
                                      "Connection refused.",
                                      "TTL expired.",
                                      "Command not supported.",
                                      "Address type not supported.",
                                      "Unknown error."
                                  };
    #endregion


    public static Socket ConnectToSocks5Proxy(string proxyAdress, ushort proxyPort, string destAddress, ushort destPort,
        string userName, string password)
    {
        IPAddress destIP = null;
        IPAddress proxyIP = null;
        byte[] request = new byte[257];
        byte[] response = new byte[257];
        ushort nIndex;

        try
        {
            proxyIP = IPAddress.Parse(proxyAdress);
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {   // get the IP address
            proxyIP = Dns.GetHostByAddress(proxyAdress).AddressList[0];
        }

        // Parse destAddress (assume it in string dotted format "212.116.65.112" )
        try
        {
            destIP = IPAddress.Parse(destAddress);
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            // wrong assumption its in domain name format "www.microsoft.com"
        }

        IPEndPoint proxyEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(proxyIP, proxyPort);

        // open a TCP connection to SOCKS server...
        Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        s.Connect(proxyEndPoint);

        nIndex = 0;
        request[nIndex++] = 0x05; // Version 5.
        request[nIndex++] = 0x01; // 2 Authentication methods are in packet...
        request[nIndex++] = 0x00; // NO AUTHENTICATION REQUIRED
        //request[nIndex++] = 0x02; // USERNAME/PASSWORD
                                  // Send the authentication negotiation request...
        s.Send(request, nIndex, SocketFlags.None);

        // Receive 2 byte response...
        int nGot = s.Receive(response, 2, SocketFlags.None);
        if (nGot != 2)
            throw new ConnectionException("Bad response received from proxy server.");

        if (response[1] == 0xFF)
        {    // No authentication method was accepted close the socket.
            s.Close();
            throw new ConnectionException("None of the authentication method was accepted by proxy server.");
        }

        byte[] rawBytes;

       
        if (/*response[1]==0x02*/false)
        {//Username/Password Authentication protocol
            nIndex = 0;
            request[nIndex++] = 0x05; // Version 5.

            // add user name
            request[nIndex++] = (byte)userName.Length;
            rawBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(userName);
            rawBytes.CopyTo(request, nIndex);
            nIndex += (ushort)rawBytes.Length;

            // add password
            request[nIndex++] = (byte)password.Length;
            rawBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(password);
            rawBytes.CopyTo(request, nIndex);
            nIndex += (ushort)rawBytes.Length;

            // Send the Username/Password request
            s.Send(request, nIndex, SocketFlags.None);
            // Receive 2 byte response...
            nGot = s.Receive(response, 2, SocketFlags.None);
            if (nGot != 2)
                throw new ConnectionException("Bad response received from proxy server.");
            if (response[1] != 0x00)
                throw new ConnectionException("Bad Usernaem/Password.");
        }
        
        // This version only supports connect command. 
        // UDP and Bind are not supported.

        // Send connect request now...
        nIndex = 0;
        request[nIndex++] = 0x05;   // version 5.
        request[nIndex++] = 0x01;   // command = connect.
        request[nIndex++] = 0x00;   // Reserve = must be 0x00

        if (destIP != null)
        {// Destination adress in an IP.
            switch (destIP.AddressFamily)
            {
                case AddressFamily.InterNetwork:
                    // Address is IPV4 format
                    request[nIndex++] = 0x01;
                    rawBytes = destIP.GetAddressBytes();
                    rawBytes.CopyTo(request, nIndex);
                    nIndex += (ushort)rawBytes.Length;
                    break;
                case AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6:
                    // Address is IPV6 format
                    request[nIndex++] = 0x04;
                    rawBytes = destIP.GetAddressBytes();
                    rawBytes.CopyTo(request, nIndex);
                    nIndex += (ushort)rawBytes.Length;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {// Dest. address is domain name.
            request[nIndex++] = 0x03;   // Address is full-qualified domain name.
            request[nIndex++] = Convert.ToByte(destAddress.Length); // length of address.
            rawBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(destAddress);
            rawBytes.CopyTo(request, nIndex);
            nIndex += (ushort)rawBytes.Length;
        }

        // using big-edian byte order
        byte[] portBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(destPort);
        for (int i = portBytes.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            request[nIndex++] = portBytes[i];

        // send connect request.
        s.Send(request, nIndex, SocketFlags.None);
        // Point of breaking !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        s.Receive(response);    // Get variable length response...
        if (response[1] != 0x00)
            throw new ConnectionException(errorMsgs[response[1]]); // Crashes the Client !!!!!!!!!!!
        // Success Connected...
        return s;
    }
}
```

### Main Code

```
   Socket s;
                // s = SocksProxy.ConnectToSocks5Proxy("127.0.0.1", 9150, "xoembwt22tmxseask2qyuudbxoubiuafw54klkwuktvv6bxbhrdffqyd.onion", 1604, "U$er", "Pa$$word!"); //NOT WORKING
                //s = SocksProxy.ConnectToSocks5Proxy("127.0.0.1", 9150, "xoembwt22tmxseask2qyuudbxoubiuafw54klkwuktvv6bxbhrdffqyd.onion", 80, "", ""); // WORKING
                s = SocksProxy.ConnectToSocks5Proxy("127.0.0.1", 9150, "xoembwt22tmxseask2qyuudbxoubiuafw54klkwuktvv6bxbhrdffqyd.onion", 1604, "", ""); //NOT WORKING
               // s = SocksProxy.ConnectToSocks5Proxy("127.0.0.1", 9150, "X.X.X.100", 1604, "", ""); //WORKING

                //client is a TCPClient
                client.Client = s;
```

## Server

### Server Class

```
public class Server : Common
    {
        private static int counter;

        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, ClientToken> clients = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ClientToken>();
        public TcpListener listener;
        private Thread listenerThread;

        public bool Active => listenerThread != null && listenerThread.IsAlive;

        public static int NextConnectionId()
        {
            int id = Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
            if (id == int.MaxValue) throw new Exception("connection id limit reached: " + id);

            return id;
        }

        private void Listen(int port)
        {
            try
            {
                listener = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
                listener.Server.NoDelay = NoDelay;
                listener.Server.SendTimeout = SendTimeout;
                listener.Start();
                Logger.Log("Server: listening port=" + port);

                while (true)
                {
                    TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                    int connectionId = NextConnectionId();

                    ClientToken token = new ClientToken(client);
                    clients[connectionId] = token;

                    Thread sendThread = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            SendLoop(connectionId, client, token.sendQueue, token.sendPending);
                        }
                        catch (ThreadAbortException) { }
                        catch (Exception exception)
                        {
                            Logger.LogError("Server send thread exception: " + exception);
                        }
                    });
                    sendThread.IsBackground = true;
                    sendThread.Start();

                    Thread receiveThread = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ReceiveLoop(connectionId, client, receiveQueue, MaxMessageSize);

                            clients.TryRemove(connectionId, out ClientToken _);

                            sendThread.Interrupt();
                        }
                        catch (Exception exception)
                        {
                            Logger.LogError("Server client thread exception: " + exception);
                        }
                    });
                    receiveThread.IsBackground = true;
                    receiveThread.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException exception)
            {
                Logger.Log("Server thread aborted. That's okay. " + exception);
            }
            catch (SocketException exception)
            {
                Logger.Log("Server Thread stopped. That's okay. " + exception);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Logger.LogError("Server Exception: " + exception);
            }
        }

        public bool Start(int port)
        {
            if (Active) return false;

            receiveQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<Message>();

            Logger.Log("Server: Start port=" + port);
            listenerThread = new Thread(() => { Listen(port); });
            listenerThread.IsBackground = true;
            listenerThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
            listenerThread.Start();
            return true;
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            if (!Active) return;

            Logger.Log("Server: stopping...");

            listener?.Stop();

            listenerThread?.Interrupt();
            listenerThread = null;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, ClientToken> kvp in clients)
            {
                TcpClient client = kvp.Value.client;
                try
                {
                    client.GetStream().Close();
                }
                catch { }

                client.Close();
            }

            clients.Clear();
        }

        public bool Send(int connectionId, byte[] data)
        {
            if (data.Length <= MaxMessageSize)
            {
                ClientToken token;
                if (clients.TryGetValue(connectionId, out token))
                {
                    token.sendQueue.Enqueue(data);
                    token.sendPending.Set();
                    return true;
                }

                Logger.Log("Server.Send: invalid connectionId: " + connectionId);
                return false;
            }

            Logger.LogError("Client.Send: message too big: " + data.Length + ". Limit: " + MaxMessageSize);
            return false;
        }

        public string GetClientAddress(int connectionId)
        {
            ClientToken token;
            if (clients.TryGetValue(connectionId, out token))
                return ((IPEndPoint) token.client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
            return "";
        }

        public bool Disconnect(int connectionId)
        {
            ClientToken token;
            if (clients.TryGetValue(connectionId, out token))
            {
                token.client.Close();
                Logger.Log("Server.Disconnect connectionId:" + connectionId);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private class ClientToken
        {
            public readonly TcpClient client;
            public readonly ManualResetEvent sendPending = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            public readonly SafeQueue<byte[]> sendQueue = new SafeQueue<byte[]>();

            public ClientToken(TcpClient client)
            {
                this.client = client;
            }
        }
    }
```

### Common

```
public abstract class Common
    {
        public static int messageQueueSizeWarning = 100000;

        public int MaxMessageSize = 2147483647;

        public bool NoDelay = true;
        protected ConcurrentQueue<Message> receiveQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<Message>();

        public int SendTimeout = 5000;

        public int ReceiveQueueCount => receiveQueue.Count;

        public bool GetNextMessage(out Message message)
        {
            return receiveQueue.TryDequeue(out message);
        }

        protected static bool SendMessagesBlocking(NetworkStream stream, byte[][] messages)
        {
            try
            {
                int packetSize = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < messages.Length; ++i)
                    packetSize += sizeof(int) + messages[i].Length;

                byte[] payload = new byte[packetSize];
                int position = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < messages.Length; ++i)
                {
                    byte[] header = Utils.IntToBytesBigEndian(messages[i].Length);

                    Array.Copy(header, 0, payload, position, header.Length);
                    Array.Copy(messages[i], 0, payload, position + header.Length, messages[i].Length);
                    position += header.Length + messages[i].Length;
                }

                stream.Write(payload, 0, payload.Length);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Logger.Log("Send: stream.Write exception: " + exception);
                return false;
            }
        }

        protected static bool ReadMessageBlocking(NetworkStream stream, int MaxMessageSize, out byte[] content)
        {
            content = null;

            byte[] header = new byte[4];
            if (!stream.ReadExactly(header, 4))
                return false;

            int size = Utils.BytesToIntBigEndian(header);

            if (size <= MaxMessageSize)
            {
                content = new byte[size];
                return stream.ReadExactly(content, size);
            }

            Logger.LogWarning("ReadMessageBlocking: possible allocation attack with a header of: " + size + " bytes.");
            return false;
        }

        protected static void ReceiveLoop(int connectionId, TcpClient client, ConcurrentQueue<Message> receiveQueue,
            int MaxMessageSize)
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            DateTime messageQueueLastWarning = DateTime.Now;

            try
            {
                receiveQueue.Enqueue(new Message(connectionId, EventType.Connected, null));

                while (true)
                {
                    byte[] content;
                    if (!ReadMessageBlocking(stream, MaxMessageSize, out content))
                        break;

                    receiveQueue.Enqueue(new Message(connectionId, EventType.Data, content));

                    if (receiveQueue.Count > messageQueueSizeWarning)
                    {
                        TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - messageQueueLastWarning;
                        if (elapsed.TotalSeconds > 10)
                        {
                            Logger.LogWarning("ReceiveLoop: messageQueue is getting big(" + receiveQueue.Count +
                                              "), try calling GetNextMessage more often. You can call it more than once per frame!");
                            messageQueueLastWarning = DateTime.Now;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Logger.Log("ReceiveLoop: finished receive function for connectionId=" + connectionId + " reason: " +
                           exception);
            }

            stream.Close();
            client.Close();

            receiveQueue.Enqueue(new Message(connectionId, EventType.Disconnected, null));
        }

        protected static void SendLoop(int connectionId, TcpClient client, SafeQueue<byte[]> sendQueue,
            ManualResetEvent sendPending)
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            try
            {
                while (client.Connected)
                {
                    sendPending.Reset();

                    byte[][] messages;
                    if (sendQueue.TryDequeueAll(out messages))
                        if (!SendMessagesBlocking(stream, messages))
                            return;

                    sendPending.WaitOne();
                }
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException) { }
            catch (ThreadInterruptedException) { }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Logger.Log("SendLoop Exception: connectionId=" + connectionId + " reason: " + exception);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: After tweaking and observing that tor.exe ignored my torrc file now it accepts my connection but i get Index was outside the bounds of the array